# Correct usage for labels.id in lm.plot?

Tags: r, plot, na, lm

Assume the following example data:

```r
data <- iris
data$Sepal.Length[1:5] <- NA
model <- lm(Sepal.Length ~ Sepal.Width + Petal.Length, data = data)
```

I am looking for the correct way to use the `labels.id` parameter in `plot.lm`.

I have tried this:

```r
plot(model, labels.id=rownames(data))
```

However, I am not sure that this gives the correct names. Some rows in `data` were not used in the model because of `NA` values. Is there an easy way to use the correct names or do I have to do something like this where I omit `NA` values from `data`:

```r
plot(model, labels.id = rownames(complete.cases(data[, "Sepal.Length"]))
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample data for a Minimal Reproducible Example please? https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I can't really provide any example, this is just a question about how the labels.id parameter works. ?lm.plot doesn't really provide help. If you want a reproducable example you can use any dataset and make a simple linear model.

Comment: You can try with a small data set yourself to see for certain, but row names are preserved when a case is dropped as missing. Try this - `x <- data.frame(Var=matrix(1:10, 10)); x; x$Var[5] <- NA; na.omit(x)`. Notice the row names are preserved and 5 is now missing.

Comment: You can provide us with an example by doing e.g. `mm <- mtcars; mm$mpg[c(1,7,20)] <- NA; m1 <- lm(mpg ~ cyl, data=mm, na.exclude=TRUE)` and see how it goes from there ...

Comment: @lennertcl, what do you expect the are the "correct" rownames? 

In the iris dataframe, they are just the integers 1 thru 150. 

If you are concerned about the 5 data points deleted due to missingness, you can't help that when doing plot(model) because the modeling step throws out those 5 points.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Answer**

The row names are preserved in the `lm` output:

```r
plot(model, labels.id = rownames(model$model))
```

**Rationale**

Internally, `lm` performs a lot of steps related to the input data. You can find a lot of information in the `lm` output. Try `str(model, max = 1)` to get an impression.

**1. Places where the row names are preserved**

```r
names(model$residuals)                 # same: names(resid(model))
names(model$fitted.values)             # same: names(fitted(model))
rownames(model$model)
```

**2. Places where you can see which rows were excluded**

```r
model$na.action                        # same: na.action(model)
attr(model$model, "na.action")
```

**3. For the latter, you can also find the row names by using `names`**

```r
names(model$na.action)                 # same: names(na.action(model))
names(attr(model$model, "na.action"))
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. However, rownames are not in my model. Therefore using `plot(model, labels.id = rownames(model$model))` just adds numbers to the plot again. I was asking about `plot(model, labels.id = rownames(dataframe))`. If this is not correct, is it possible to add rownames to model in some way that doesn't affect the model?

Comment: Well, in that case you can just do `rownames(dataframe)[-model$na.action]`, to subset out those rows. Does that make sense?

Comment: Assuming that you used `dataframe` as input for `lm`: Yes. Or, well, I'm not aware of exceptions.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I was just editing because I misread it.